# How can i grab numbers out of strings when the length of the string changes?

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a list of strings, such as `(q1,0)->(q2,_,R)` and i need to pick out the q1, 0 and then the q2,_,R. I would use `.substring(enter numbers)`, but the placement of those characters changes in the list. For instance, I also have `(q11,1)->(q11,1,L)`. So, while for the first string I could do .substring(1,3) to grab the q1, then .substring(4,5) to grab the 0, I can't do the same for the other string.

I'm getting an idea that I could find the length of the string, and then use substring with different numbers for each length. I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: Use Regex to eliminate the characters like ( ) -> etc..

Comment: give a concrete example of exactly what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could the regex as `\\(([^)]+)\\)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String str = "(q1,0)->(q2,_,R)";
   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)").matcher(str);
   while(m.find()) {
          System.out.println(m.group(1));    
   }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
q1,0
q2,_,R
```

The regex can be read as follows:

- `\\( - character (`
- `( - start match group`
- `[-  one of these characters`
- `^ - not the following character`
- `) - with the previous ^, this means "every character except )"`
- `+ - one of more of the stuff from the [] set`
- `) - stop match group`
- `\\) -  literal closing paranthesis`

Comment: @Austin Story, could you check this what you expecting or something else?

Comment: That looks good! I've used regex in the past but have difficulty understanding it. Thank you very much!